# How can we create a table in Entity Framework with customised column name as Primary key

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I wanted to have my own customised name for the Primary Key column in Entity Framework instead of having primary key column name as "Id" in EntityFramework. Suppose If I wanted to create a table say "Student", then I wanted to have table with Primary key column name as "StudentId". And I wanted to use this column name "StudentId" in c# code for "Student" table querying and joining with other tables instead of using the column name as "Id". And the table should create in SQL with primary column name as "StudentId". May I know how can we achieve this.

Comment: Can you show the class for the `Student` entity? Normally, put `[Key]` above the column in the class.

Comment: Nothing in EF says that the primary key has to be called "Id". What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes. For all entities I tried by giving the primary key column as "Id". So when I wanted to set the primary column as foreign key column to other table, the same column name("Id") exist for other table as well. To avoid that I wanted to know this. Thanks youzer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the KeyAttribute for the property you want to use as the Primary Key:

```
class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
}
```